# SharedPreferences (on a null object reference)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I try to add and get data using sharedPreferences, but I only receive this error in logcat:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences
android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'
on a null object reference
```

The line of code:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); // <-error here
```

I need create first the xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: have you written this code in the main activity ? or anywhere else . please explain more .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize it after activity created:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences prefs;

onCreate(){
    prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
}
```